# PyInstaller + PyQt5 + QML: QtQuick is not installed

Tags: python, qml, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I'm trying to build an app using pyinstaller, PyQt5 and qml (see files below) using the following command.

```
pyrcc5 pyqt5_qml.qrc > pyqt5_qml_qrc.py
pyinstaller -w -F --noupx pyqt5_qml.py
```

(OSX 10.11.1, python 3.5.0, qt 5.5.1, pyinstaller 3.0)

The pyqt5_qml.py runs fine (open an "Hello world!" window) but the built app complains about `module "QtQuick" version 2.4 is not installed`. I guess the module has not been included into the built app but I'm not sure how to tell pyinstaller to do it.

pyqt5_qml.py:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQml
import pyqt5_qml_qrc

def main():
    global app 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl('qrc:/hello.qml'))
    root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

hello.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Window")
    Rectangle {
        width: 360
        height: 360
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Hello World"
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pyqt5_qml.qrc:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>hello.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help

I was struggling with the same problem

After hours, I did something simple, but for me it worked

In my **main.py** I mean the file in which you load the QML file I added

```
import PyQt5.QtQuick
```

And then run pyinstaller :

```
pyinstaller  -F  - -onefile main.py
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me it on Windows this ended up being the QML2_IMPORT_PATH environment variable had not been set. Once I set this to "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\qml" it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Working with PyInstaller I've noticed that it simply fails to bundle QML dependencies then freezing an app. You can check whether it is your case as well by copying `QtQuick` and `QtQuick.2` folders from python site packages  (`<your_python_path>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\qml`) and placing it near freezed executable:

```
QtQuick
QtQuick.2
your_executable.exe
```

If app works after this, you can edit `.spec` file to bundle these folders automatically (pyinstaller generate `.spec`-file on first run).

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import os
import site

block_cipher = None

site_packages_dir = site.getsitepackages()[1]
qml_dir = os.path.join(site_packages_dir, 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'qml')

added_files = [
    (os.path.join(qml_dir, 'QtQuick'), 'QtQuick'),
    (os.path.join(qml_dir, 'QtQuick.2'), 'QtQuick.2'),
]

a = Analysis(['pyqt5_qml.py'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=True,
)

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name='pyqt5_qml')
```

Then try to run `pyinstaller` against this spec-file: `pyinstaller pyqt5_qml.spec`