# Use PyInstaller to build PyQt5 with QML in --onefile

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtquick2

I want to build a portable executable (at least all the source files in one folder) of a PyQt5 GUI application with QML (for Material themes) via PyInstaller in both Windows 10 and Ubuntu. However, after the executable has been built successfully, it crashes with some error messages.

`material.py`:

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl('basic.qml'))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`basic.qml`: (which is copied from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-material.html))

```py
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Purple

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        RadioButton { text: qsTr("Small") }
        RadioButton { text: qsTr("Medium");  checked: true }
        RadioButton { text: qsTr("Large") }
    }
}
```

I use the following commands to build the executable:

```
pyinstaller ./material.py --onefile
```

After built, the executable shows the error messages. In Windows 10:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///D:/test/dist/basic.qml:1 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Cannot load library D:\test\dist\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugin.dll: ???????w?????C
```

In Linux:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///media/username/EA9E5E009E5DC5AB/test/dist/basic.qml:1 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Cannot load library /media/username/EA9E5E009E5DC5AB/test/dist/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5: symbol _ZN3QV46Object11markObjectsEPNS_4Heap4BaseEPNS_15ExecutionEngineE, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Qml.so.5 with link time reference)
```

The file tree of the project is:

```
. (test)
+-- build
|   +-- (some files generate by PyInstaller)
+-- dist
|   +-- QtQuick (the folder copied from Python site-packages)
|   |   +-- (some files copied form Python site-packages)
|   +-- QtQuick.2 (the folder copied from Python site-packages)
|   |   +-- plugins.qmltypes
|   |   +-- qmldir
|   |   +-- qtquick2plugin.dll (or 'libqtquick2plugin.so' in Linux)
|   +-- basic.qml
|   +-- material.exe (or 'material' in Linux)
+-- basic.qml
+-- material.py
+-- material.spec
```

I copied two folders, `QtQuick` and `QtQuick.2`, since I had had the same problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33965197/8789738) and I do the same thing as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629660/8789738). I have been looking for the solution for a week, having no clues why it cannot load the library.

Comment: when you use the `--onefile` option it is not necessary to pass the .so or .dll, in my case I have done the tests and it works correctly. What version of pyinstaller are you using?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using PyInstaller **3.3**. I am not sure what do you mean that it's not necessary to pass the `.so` or `.dll` for using the `--onefile` option. If I don't move the two folders, `QtQuick` and `QtQuick.2`, next to my executable, the program will show module "QtQuick.Controls", "QtQuick" and other things imported in the `basic.qml` is not installed. For instance, `file:///media/username/EA9E5E009E5DC5AB/test/dist/basic.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed`.

Comment: Also, for more information, the PyQt version I use is **5.10.1** with Python **3.6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround with Pyinstaller `3.3.1` and PyQt5 `>= 5.11` to solve this problem.

Use `pyrcc5` to compile QML files and import them into Python scripts. Thus, Pyinstaller would package them automatically without the need to put QML files next to the executable.

In this case, compile `basic.qml` with `pyrcc5`,

```sh
pyrcc5 -o src.py src.qrc
```

Then, modify `material.py`,

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import src # import the resource file compiled by pyrcc5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Material"
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl('qrc:/basic.qml')) # modify the url for qrc format
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Finally, use the following command to package the source codes.

```sh
pyinstaller material.py --windowed --onefile --hidden-import PyQt5.sip --hidden-import PyQt5.QtQuick
```

The hidden imports are required as the new version of PyQt5 has modified some module names and thus made them incompatible with current Pyinstaller hooks.

However, after the codes have been packaged, the result release binary might have some issue regarding the QtQuick2 Style display (esp. for Material and Imagine themes). You could fix this problem by using the latest developed version of Pyinstaller (`3.4 dev`).

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me, i had tried everything you had wrote and still same problem.

Comment: it is not clear what is the src.qrc and what it contains